# Where can I find the PyBluez API

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluez, pybluez

I understood from [Bluetooth for Programmers](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rudolph/Teaching/Articles/BTBook.pdf) chapter 2, that the PyBluez API does provide functions like **discover_devices** and **lookup_name**. 
 
 However I have not found any API documentation for PyBluez. 
 
 What I am looking for is the complete list of functions available in PyBluez as well as the list of arguments for these functions - f.e. what are the arguments available for discover_devices, what are the arguments available for lookup_name....

Answer (score 7):

[Here](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/docs/index.html) it is, the most useless documentation ever

Comment: I'm amazed that PyBluez is still the top result for bluetooth on python with this level of quality

Comment: @AlexLamson is there a better alternative for BLE on python?

Comment: @jaaq Supposedly python3.3 sockets should natively support it, but I haven't tried it. Also sockets aren't the simplest things in world to work with if you're trying to do something simple.

Answer (score 3):

Found it:

- Download the PyBluez sources from it [git repository](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez)
- Extract the sources
- Open the file pybluez\docs\index.html - Everything is available from there